# Console don't let my applet run because of a file

Tags: java, file, exception, applet, accesscontrolexception

I am working in an applet. It works perfect with Eclipse but when I try to run from Console it gives me this stack trace:

```
C:\Course Technology\src>appletviewer TestJAlienHunt.html

Path for file entered D:\Course Technology\AssignmentFinal\scoreFile.txt java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "D:\Course Technology\AssignmentFinal\scoreFile.txt" "read")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:366)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:555)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkRead(SecurityManager.java:888)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.checkRead(WindowsPath.java:792)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.checkAccess(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:360)
    at java.nio.file.Files.exists(Files.java:2311)
    at ReadFile.fileExists(ReadFile.java:47)
    at JAlienHunt.readScore(JAlienHunt.java:187)
    at JAlienHunt.init(JAlienHunt.java:73)
    at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(AppletPanel.java:434)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

The file has permission to read and write, why I am getting this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An applet needs to be digitally signed by you and trusted by the end user before it can access the local file system on the *user's computer.*

I highlight *user's computer* because that is where any `File` will equate to.  There is no option for getting a `File` pointing to the server.  If this is read only and the server hosts the resource, access it by `URL`.

Comment: Wow, that's new! As you can see I am new with applets. I am working in a project and that is part of the requirement but the book doesn't say anything about that... Thanks, I will dig more into this.